# undefined after declaring the variable

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>moving word</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="word">w3resource</p>
</body>

</html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="five.js"></script>





function MovingLetters() {
  var text = document.getElementById("word").value;
  var len = text.length;
  var lastletter = text.charAt(len-1);
  text = text.substring(0,len-1);
  text = lastletter + text;
}

MovingLetters();

$(function() {
  setInterval(MovingLetters, 1000);
});
```

Console gives me :

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

No idea why it is undefined because I defined it 2 lines before that one while that one reflects to a `<p>` in the html code that runs before the js script runs. Can someone help?

Comment: Use `var text = document.getElementById("word").innerHTML;` instead since the element with the id of `word` is not a text input.

Comment: Your script should be between script tags. Maybe it was a copy and paste thing...

Answer (score 2):

using `value` is for input elements, you should use `textContent`, `innerText` or if you want the html `innerHTML`:

```
var text = document.getElementById("word").textContent;
```

```js
function MovingLetters() {
  var word = document.getElementById("word")
  var text = word.textContent;
  var len = text.length;
  var lastletter = text.charAt(len - 1);
  text = text.substring(0, len - 1);
  text = lastletter + text;
  word.textContent = text
}

MovingLetters();
setInterval(MovingLetters, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="word">w3resource</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont't want the value you want what's called innerHTML. you can achieve this by doing `document.getElementById("word").innerHTML.length`.